# Determine whether the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are open with respect to the metric $d$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Consider the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with its standard metric
>   $d$ given by
>
> $$d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2}$$
>
> Determine whether the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are open
>   with respect to the metric $d$.
>
> Justify your answers.
>
> a) $ A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x \geq 0\}$.

I have been given the solution to this question but don't quite understand it. This is the solution I have been given:

Let $r > 0$.Denote the point $(0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ by $0$ and consider the open ball $B_r(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. For the point $p_r = (-\frac{r}{2}, 0)$ we have $$d(p_r,0) = \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{4}} = \frac{r}{2}<r$$

and therefore $p_r \in B_r(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Note that $0 \in A$. If $A$ were open, then we would be able to find a radius $r>0$ with the property that $B_r(0)$ is never entirely contained in $A$. Thus, $A$ is not an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the metric $d$.

Looking at this solution I have a couple of questions. Why is the point $p_r = (-\frac{r}{2}, 0)$ used? I understand where the $d(p_r,0)$ comes from. 
If someone could help me break it down a bit. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's used because we know it will not be in the set. You could use any $w; -r < w < 0$ then $d(w,0)< r$ but $(w,0)\not \in B_r(0,0)$.

Comment: I would recommend drawing a diagram. The set $A $ defines the region right to the $y$ axis(includes  $y $ axis as well). Now if you take any point on the $y $ axis, you can see that every ball around that point intersects the left side region.

Comment: If you don't like $(\frac {-r}2, 0)$ you can use $(0.128674\times r, -.05892789\times r)$ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the proof is that it's not an open set because $(0,0)$ is not an interior point.  For that matter $(0,k)$ for any $k$ is not an interior point, but the proof choose $(0,0)$ because it makes the math easier.

To show $(0,0)$ fails the interior test set we have to show there does *NOT* exist an $r > 0$ so that $B_r(0,0)$ is contained in $A$.

To do that we just have to find a point $(j,k)$ so that $d((0,0),(j,k)) < r$ and $(j,k) \in A$.  If $(j,k)\not \in A$ then $j < 0$.  And it doesn't matter what $k$ is.  So to make the math easy we will let $k = 0$.

So we need a $(j,0)$ so that 1:  $\sqrt{(j-0)^2 + (0-0)^2} = |j| < r$.  and 2: $(j,0) \not \in A$ i.e. $j < 0$.

So we need $-r < j < 0$.

.... and they chose $\frac {-r}2$.  It actually doesnt matter *what* you choose.  They chose $(\frac {-r}2,0)$ because it makes the math easier.

The could have chosen $(-\frac{r}{e},10^{-57}r)$  but that would make our math hard as hell. [ $\sqrt{(-\frac{r}{e}-0)^2 + (10^{-57}r - 0)^2} < r$]

But with testing is $(\frac {-r}2,0)\in B_r(0,0)$ the math is easy.

Is $d((\frac {-r}2,0),(0,0)) < r$?  Of course.

And is $(\frac {-r}2, 0) \in A$?  Of course not.

So $A$ is not open.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake at the end. If the set were to be open, then since $(0,0) \in A$, there must be a ball centered there entirely inside $A$, as opposed to what the solution says. Then you use the fact that for any $r>0$, $p_r$ is inside the ball of radius $r$ around the origin. Since this point is not in $A$, the ball can not be contained in $A$, so it can’t be open.

Comment: How is this any different than what the solution said?  And what mistake?

Comment: "If $A$ were open, then we would be able to find a radius $r>0$ with the property that $B_r(0)$ is never entirely contained in $A$." This is not what open means. It is actually the opposite.

Comment: That's badly worded but they are saying that Br (0) is never entirely in A.  So A isn't open.

Comment: I agree that is what they probably meant, but what they said is the opposite of that.